# How to find all Subtasks where parent is assigned to me

Tags: jira, jql

We're using Jira stories to cover specific areas of functionality that a team member owns.

We're using sub-tasks to create a dependency chain to show when all bugs and enhancements have been finished for a story.

I would love to be able to create a query that shows subtasks where parent assignee is current user. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Volodymyr's answer is close, but the correct query is actually this:

```
issueFunction in subTasksOf("assignee = currentUser()"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with a standard JIRA JQL, but for JIRA server there are couple plugins that add handy JQL functions.

With ScriptRunner https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner:

```
type = sub-task and issueFunction in parentsOf("assignee = currentUser()"))
```